# Microsoft Graph API - Search email using application permission

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to search email using Graph API in my own developed application. By referring to these threads - [Graph Api: Region is required when request with application permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/927053/graph-api-region-is-required-when-request-with-app.html)  ,   [How to use Graph API Sharepoint Search from console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74154046/how-to-use-graph-api-sharepoint-search-from-console-app/74154740)   ,   [Search content with application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-searchall)    ,   `I tried to run the search which resulted in Application permission is only supported for the following entity types:site, list, listItem, drive and driveItem.`   (Request and response json is below).

**Does it mean that using an app like a console application developed in C# will not be able to search the emails** (as message is not mentioned in error response - only these are mentioned: *site, list, listItem, drive and driveItem*) **even if it has required secret, auth token and permissions?**

Request:
URL : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query
Request Payload:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "person"
      ],
      "query": {
        "queryString": "contoso"
      },
      "Region" : "NAM",
      "from": 0,
      "size": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": "Application permission is only supported for the following entity types:site, list, listItem, drive and driveItem.",
        "target": "",
        "httpCode": 403
    },
    "Instrumentation": {
        "TraceId": "7174e417-a2fe-02e5-1523-1fcda7a66886"
    }
}
```

Comment: I only found [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-messages#known-limitations) for searching oneself's messages and [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) for searching  a specific users' messages

Comment: Second API is the one which we are already using.. can we use List messages api to search for specific text in body or attachments?

Comment: I'm afraid not.... but I think you can also test it in your app, because you have so many emails for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can search other user emails with application permissions this way:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[USER]/messages?$search=[search query]`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the restriction on entity types

Instead of application permissions, try delegated permissions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-overview?tabs=http#delegated-permissions

You should be able to search in your emails, but only your own emails.

Comment: Perhaps you could include an example in order to improve the clarity/helpfulness of your answer?